# How much is it common that we put something in parenthesis for formal writing?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example, please take a look at the upper map illustrated, here: https://ielts-simon.com/ielts-help-and-english-pr/2018/07/ielts-writing-task-1-band-9-map-answer.html
To avoid writing a similar sentence, is it possible we write a sentence like below in our writing:

> The west (***east***) entrance road to the town bifurcates in two forks in order that its southern branch ends up to the school (***the park***).

Answer (score 1):

Are you, perhaps, a computer programmer?

Your use of parenthesis looks more like a computer language. It is perfectly accurate, but not easy to read.

Parenthesis are quite common in formal writing. Legal documents make use of them to clarify and make an expression more precise. Essayists and journalists put asides and comments in parenthesis.

It is also possible to use them, as you have done to compress two similar sentences into one. This should be used only rarely. Your example is just confusing.  I'm not sure what the IELTS task is; do you have to describe the changes to Islip?  I don't see quite what your sentence is describing.

Comment: yes, we have to describe the changes. But it is better that we, firstly, explain about the first map of the city, like what I tried to do in my sentence. Do you believe that the sentence is incapable of describing the map?

Comment: I don't believe I could understand your sentence as a description of the first map.  I don't know what you mean by "the left entrance" (left and right depend on where you are standing)  I don't understand "biuficates in two forks  I don't know what you mean by left-wing-branch.  And there are grammatical errors such as "is ended". Sorry, but you will do best if you start again.  Use East/west and you can talk about side roads that lead to a school and a park.

Comment: Thank you. According to your constructive comments, I have done some changes, like using the "west" in lieu of the "left", the "southern branch" instead of "right-(left-)wing"; moreover, I correct the grammatical error.

Comment: "bifurcates in two forks" is redundant.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. What do you propose instead of that? If that redundancy gets eliminated, do I have a correct sentence? If not, could I ask you to put forward the correct sentence?

Comment: You haven't understood the _ring road_.